# Pass digit keys in normal mode as an argument of vim's function

Tags: regex, vim

I want to see the output message:

```
1234
```

when I type `1234<Enter>` in normal mode of vim.

I've tried to write some vim script here

```
function! PrintNum(n)
    echo n
endfunction

nmap n<Enter> call PrintNum(n)
```

where `n` here is just a dummy variable that represents regex `\d+`.

How could I use some kind of regex in map command?

Note that I'm also not sure if I should use `nmap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

```
function! PrintNum(n)
    echo a:n
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Enter> :<C-u>call PrintNum(v:count)<CR>
```

#### Explanation

- There are no dummy variables in a mapping; it's executed just as typed. However, the special variable `v:count` gets the number that can be put before any command.
- Here, I've passed this into the function as argument `n` (internally referenced as `a:n`), but I could have used `v:count` also directly inside the function.
- The `:` command by default turns a count into a range, as we want a separate `:call`, we remove this range via `<C-u>`.
- The mapping (command-line mode) is concluded by pressing Enter: `<CR>`. The `<silent>` avoids that you briefly see the mapped keys.
- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: Is is possible to read two numbers before enter e.g. `123 456 <CR>`?

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: So, the numbers are space-separated? Well, that's just two mappings, one for `<Space>`, that saves `v:count` to a variable, then mine for `<Enter>` that uses the saved variable and the new `v:count`. Perfectly doable, but very odd for Vim.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought that it's too complicated then I chose to ask the simple one first. My final goal is just to use those two numbers in function.

Comment: Should I open my new question as new post?

Comment: Yes, please post a new question, with the exact problem you're trying to solve. I'm sure there's a better way...